# Evolus Pencil export page as pdf does not work on Windows

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xulrunner, evolus-pencil

I am running Firefox version 31.0, did install pencil evolus (firefox extension).

When I try to export a page to png or pdf I bump into a stall export dialog forever or sometimes it shuts down without exporting.

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: That's an awesome extension btw. I used to use it before I got Microsoft Visio. This is probably an issue you need to bring up with the addon developer.

Comment: Very true @Noitidart,Its is  very handy for Design

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:

PDF/PNG export problems are usually caused by backwards-incompatible Firefox/XUL API changes.

You should try the latest standalone version of my fork where it should be fixed: http://github.com/prikhi/pencil

(the original devs stopped development circa 2013)

Comment: If you forked it and are maintaining it, and the original licensing permitted doing so, then you should seriously consider submitting it as a new add-on to AMO. Give it a new name (e.g. "Evolus Pencil - revived") and a new ID. This is the normal and recommended method of doing this (assuming you can't get the original author to authorize you on AMO to take it over, or have joint authorship). Doing so is much better for the community (lets anyone search for it on AMO and install it) than just having a github fork (effectively is just for yourself, or very few others).

Comment: A release on AMO is the eventual plan :) My first priority is getting all the builds working & looking over AMO submission docs. I will update my answer when it exists.